# segmentation fault(core dumped) codeblocks

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I cannot understand why I keep getting the segmentation fault.

I use codeblocks and it compiles successfully, but the code doesn't execute. At the the time of execution, I keep getting this error.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *nc(int data)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node *)(malloc(sizeof(struct node)));

    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head;

    head->data = 5;
    struct node *a = nc(19);
    struct node *b = nc(25);
    struct node *c = nc(12);

    head->next = a;
    a->next = b;
    b->next = c;
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d \n", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn to use a debugger. Just because code compiles doesn't mean it's correct. Far from it. You've made an invalid memory reference somewhere. If you want to learn to be a good programmer, you need to learn how to find such errors. So what have you tried?

Comment: Hint: What's the value of `head` when you do `head->data = 5;`?

Comment: thanks for fast reply! I have got the mistake i have made

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node *head;
```

"head" is NULL at this point.
You have to allocate memory like you did in the case of "temp".

```
struct node *head = (struct node *)(malloc(sizeof(struct node)));
```